# When is "voir" followed by "de"?

Tags: grammaire, de

The following sentence is said by a character in [this](https://ici.tou.tv/alix-et-les-merveilleux/S01E54?lectureauto=1) tv show (around 2:15) :

> Ah non? Alors, j'imagine que tu ne verrais pas d'inconvénient si je te
> demandais de t'approcher pour sentir cette magnifique fleur?

On [the WordReference page](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/voir) for "voir", most examples sentences in the form of "voir + [noun phrase]" do not have a "de" after voir:

- Nous avons vu ta femme hier au marché. // Tu vois le petit roux là-bas ? C'est mon fils.
- Je vais voir le médecin.
- Je vois bien ce tableau au-dessus de la cheminée.

And only one entry has an example sentence with "de" after voir (but this entry just says "voir"; it does not say "voir [de qch]":

- Le directeur ne voit pas d'un bon œil cette réunion.

Why is the "de" in "tu ne verrais pas d'inconvénient"? When should a "de" appear after "voir", and when shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unrelated to the verb *voir*. *Inconvénient* is indefinite. The indefinite article **un** becomes **de** when following a negation:

> Tu vois **un** petit roux là-bas ? Non, je ne vois pas **de** petit roux.

> Tu vas voir **un** médecin ? Non, je ne vais pas voir **de** médecin.

> Tu verrais **un** inconvénient... ? Non, je ne verrais pas **d**'inconvénient...

The pronoun used to refer to the object will vary depending on whether it is definite or not:

> Tu vois **le** maître-nageur ? Non, je ne **le** vois pas.
> Tu vois **un** maître-nageur ? Non, je n'**en** vois pas.

*Voir **d**'un bon œil* is a different case. Here ***de*** is a preposition, not an article.

Comment: ah, i should have known this already, (but i didn't realize the consequence of "en" in answering "Non, je n'en vois pas"). however, now I want to ask about "d'un  bon oeil". why is the preposition "de" used here, but in no other sentences? can I just take out the "de", and instead say "Voir un bon oeil"?

Comment: oops. never mind about my "d'un bon oeil" question. i suspect it's some stylistic inversion. if i rearrange the sentence to become more usual, it becomes: "Le directeur ne voit pas cette réunion d'un bon œil.", which is still a grammatical structure i don't recognize, but maybe "d'un bon oeil" is an expression

Comment: *Voir d'un bon œil*  is indeed an idiom (to look at it favorably). Similar expressions are *marcher d'un bon pas*, *se lever de bonne heure*...